# How to pass data to a parent component without closing the angular material dialog on button click

Tags: angular, angular-material

how to pass the data from a **popup (angular material dialog )** to **parent component** on button click, **without closing** the **popup**.

I have no idea how to do that, can anyone please help me out with the solution.
Thanks in advance.

**parentcomponent.html**

```
<button (click)="addUser()">
```

**parentComponent.ts**

```
addUser(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddUser, {
      width: '350px'
    });
}
```

adduserComponent.ts

How to pass data without closing the dailog

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76954718/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: Doesn't [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-overview) help?

Comment: @msrumon that example didn't help the dialog popup shouldn't close

Answer (score 1):

Without closing the dialog, you need to call a service from your dialog component:

```
class DialogComponent {
    constructor(
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Data, 
      private myService: MyService
    ) {}

    sendDataWithoutClosingDialog() {
        this.myService.setData(this.data);
    }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class MyService {
    data$: Subject<Data> = new Subject<Data>();

    setData(data: Data) {
        this.data$.next(data);
    }
}
```

And then the parent component can subscribe to the service and load the data:

```
class ParentComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.data$.subscribe(data => {
            // do something with data
        });
    }
}
```

This will let the dialog stay open without closing it. The service is the instance between the parent and dialog component to transfer the data.

Hopefully this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can pass to your modal the "parent"

```
export interface DialogData {
  parent:any;
}

addUser(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddUser, {
      width: '350px',
      data:{parent:this}
    });
}
```

And in your AddUSer

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) {}
```

See an example in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yugmcq?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html,src%2Fexample%2Fdialog-overview-example.html) (in the stackblitz, when you change the input, change the variable `variable` in parent)

NOTE: Really this create a hard dependence between the dialog and the parent and it would be desirable another way to solve the real problem: "Really it's necessary?"